# Generate string with three characters

Tags: java

I am experimenting with using Java to generate random IDs or license plates (containing strings of random letters and/or numbers) using math.random method.

Is there a way to generate a random string of exactly three characters between A to Z (ex: ZJW or LRP), using math.random, without resorting to random class method? Basically, use the random method only once instead of something like:

```
char a = (char) (Math.random()*26+'A');
char b = (char) (Math.random()*26+'A');
char c = (char) (Math.random()*26+'A');      
System.out.println("" + a + b + c);
```

All my research online on this solution only point to the random class :(.

Comment: Why don't you want to use random()? What advantages do you need that you can't get with it

Comment: Your code is already working and it won't get any simpler than that. There is no problem at all, voting to close this post.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. This piece of code generates 3 random characters and prints them out.

Comment: Whats wrong with the current code?  If you do not want to repeat it just throw them into a method that returns a `String` instead of printing.

Comment: I would use  ```char a = (char) (65 + new Random().nextInt(25));```

Comment: @MatthewKerian, I do not want to use the random class (Random random = new Random();), as I have not studied it yet. I am trying to find a way using the math.random method, only once, without having to do the math.random three times.

Comment: @Anne Bailly Do you mean _using_ three times, or _writing_ it three times, because you can make a helper method that creates a random once and returns a character with a single line.  However, this is pretty pointless.  But you only need to _write_ it once though.

Comment: But why? I can't see any reason to do it once over doing it three times?

Comment: only one call: generate a random number between 0 and 26*26*26 and then get the module 26 of it, of it divided by 26 and of it divided by 26*26 - add 'A' to the 3 results of modulo - and write a lot of comments to explain what you are doing (why?)

Comment: @Nexevis, I mean writing the math.random formula three times, which is what I do not want. I am OK with using the method multiple times, such as in a loop, to get a three-character string.

Comment: @MatthewKerian, I agree that the code I have, that's proven to work, is simple, but...it seems inefficient to have to rely on three separate math.random instances to get a 3-char string. I am trying to see if there's a way to do it with only one instance of math.random.

Comment: I don't know the purpose of this question, but you could use ```char a  = (char) (90 - System.currentTimeMillis() % 30)```; which of course is not quite random.

Comment: @AnneBailly  seen my comment? BTW there is no **instance** of math.random - it is a static method of `Math` and probably calling it 3 times instead of some additional math is no penalty

Comment: This is an advanced level micro-optimization, the code you have is fine

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger, I did see your comment, and thank you for pointing out that instance is not a correct reference in terms of math.random.

Comment: "Micro-optimization" the correct idea here.  C.f. [Premature Optimization is the Root of All Evil.](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/)  These sorts of ideas (worrying about "optimization") causes far more mistakes than leaving code alone.

Answer (score 1):

if you insist on using only one Random call, you can do:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int r = (int) (Math.random() * 999999);
        double N = 26.0/99.0;

        char a = (char) ((r - (r / 100) * 100) * N + 'A');
        char b = (char) ((r / 100 - (r / 10000) * 100) * N + 'A');
        char c = (char) ((r / 10000 - (r / 1000000) * 100) * N + 'A');

        System.out.println("" + a + b + c);
    }
}
```

this is 10 random string generated by this code :

```
RLN
JMZ
SBZ
NSA
XJM
JGL
PSJ
ZEO
DNX
WLT
```

you can also use `RandomStringUtils` from Apache commons-lang:

```
RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(3).toUpperCase()
```

Comment: "using math.random" from OP

Comment: Why do people always suggest downloading a new library for an insanely simple task?

Comment: @Matthew Kerian The kicker is that this library uses java.util.Random anyway...

Comment: friends, I edited my answer